# WebRTC - How to change the audio track for a existing stream

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I have a webRTC connection established with audio and video.

On the caller side, I'd like to change the **audio input**.

*e.g. the User changes the `audioinput` from a dropdown list.*

What's the workflow to substitute the **audio track** of an existing stream?

Can I add another **audio track** and make one active over the other? how?

Looks like I may need to call `getUserMedia` again passing constraints (?), which to my understanding comes to create a New `mediaStream` instances and not modify the existing.

Comment: Modify the MediaStream in an active peerconnection, the peerconnection object will fire an onnegotiationneeded event. Handle that event and re-exchange SDPs.

Comment: thx. Could you detail this in as an Answer below (sequence of functions to call). I think this will create a new MediaStream with a different ID right? So that wouldn't be changing the audio track of an existing MediaStream (keeping the same ID) but rather renegociating the connection with a new MediaStream that will contain the same video + a different audio track.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56944864/can-we-remove-and-add-audio-stream-dynamically-in-webrtc-video-call-without-rene

Answer (score 3):

There is now a much simpler API for this operation: [RTCRtpSender.replaceTrack(](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCRtpSender/replaceTrack)).

It could look something like this:

```
const currentSenders = peerConnection.getSenders();

const currentAudioSender = currentSenders.find((s) => s.track.kind === 'audio');

currentAudioSender.replaceTrack(newAudioTrack);
```

Answer (score 2):

For us it looks something like this:

```
const replaceTrack = async (peerConnection, oldSender, track, stream) => {
  peerConnection.removeTrack(oldSender);

  const newSender = peerConnection.addTrack(track, stream);

  const localSdp = await peerConnection.createOffer({ offerToReceiveAudio: 1 });
  await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(reply);

  const response = await sendOffer(peerConnection.localDescription);

  const description = new RTCSessionDescription(response);
  peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(description);

  return newSender;
}
```